# Fast algorithms to implement left shift while XORing every color of an RGB image 

Tags: matlab, rgb

I want to XOR every bit of an RGB image after converting it to binary (pixel color wise) by `dec2bin()` function. First, I declared an array `scr(8)=0`, containing all zeros, now what i want is that when `ar(1)=xor(scr(1),pic(1))` is done, it should be stored in `scr(8)=ar(1)`,`scr(7)=scr(8)`,`scr(8)=ar(1)` and so on until the end,
I have written the code but it takes alot of time to process.
If you know of a way to speed up the code, please help me. I'm stuck here and have final presentations ahead.

This is my code:

```
pic=imread('peppers.png');
[imr,imc,clr]=size(pic);
scr(8)=0;
i=8;
img2=pic;
pic2(8)=0;
pic1(8)=0;
for row=1:imr;

    for col=1:imc

        for k=1:clr  

           img2(row,col,k)=bitxor(pic(row,col,k),66);
           pic1=dec2bin(img2(row,col,k),8);
           for n=1:8
           pic2(n)=xor(pic1(n),scr(n));
           if n==1
              scr(i)=pic2(n);
           end
           if n==2
              scr(i-1)=scr(i);
               scr(i)=pic2(n);
               end
               if n==3
                scr(i-2)=scr(i-1);
                scr(i-1)=scr(i);   
                scr(i)=pic2(n);
               end
               if n==4

                scr(i-3)=scr(i-2);
                scr(i-2)=scr(i-1);
                scr(i-1)=scr(i);   
                scr(i)=pic2(n);
               end
               if n==5
                 scr(i-4)=scr(i-3);  
                 scr(i-3)=scr(i-2);  
                scr(i-2)=scr(i-1);
                scr(i-1)=scr(i);
                 scr(i)=pic2(n);
               end
                if n==6
                scr(i-5)=scr(i-4);   
                scr(i-4)=scr(i-3); 
                scr(i-3)=scr(i-2);
                scr(i-2)=scr(i-1);
                scr(i-1)=scr(i);  
                 scr(i)=pic2(n);
                end
                if n==7
                scr(i-6)=scr(i-5);    
                scr(i-5)=scr(i-4); 
                scr(i-4)=scr(i-3);
                scr(i-3)=scr(i-2);
                scr(i-2)=scr(i-1);
                scr(i-1)=scr(i); 
                scr(i)=pic2(n);
                end
                if n==8
                 scr(i-7)=scr(i-6);        
                 scr(i-6)=scr(i-5);  
                scr(i-5)=scr(i-4);
                scr(i-4)=scr(i-3);
                scr(i-3)=scr(i-2);
                scr(i-2)=scr(i-1);
                scr(i-1)=scr(i);
                scr(i)=pic2(n);
                end

           end
           pic3=int2str(pic2);
           img2(row,col,k)=bin2dec(pic3);


        end

     end
end


imwrite(img2,'peppers2.png');
imshow('peppers2.png');
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why don't you use the built-in [BITSHIFT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitshift.html)? Also, since [BITXOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitxor.html) works on uint8, you could replace your function by

```
pic=imread('peppers.png');
pic2 = bitxor(pic,uint8(66)); %# xor with 66
pic2 = bitshift(pic2,1); %# shift to the left by one
```